# marquee html starts wrongly in chrome

Tags: html, marquee

```
 <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="2" direction="right" width="70%" style="background-color: transparent; height: 18px;" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 //inside html
        </marquee>
```

The errro I am getting is in chrome - The inside html is behaving differently then in chrome and IE. It starts with the html displayed and graduatly disappears, where as in chrom and IE,it starts empty and slowly appears (and them disappears).

I want the behaviour like in chrome and IE.

I was not able to replicate this error in jsfiddle, but here it is anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/opmaster/Sm4CH/1/

Comment: Versions of Chrome and IE? [I don't get the described behaviour with mine]

Comment: chrome 22.0.1229.94 - latest. As I said, I can't replicate this behaiviour in the jsfiddle, but It happens in my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your doctype to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: hi zomboble, this is not an option for due to the fact that i'm icluding the marquee in the website(which is a vbulletin framework)